# How to explode a string into an array with the string as Keys and the value true

Tags: php, arrays

I have:

```
$string = "option1,option2,option8";
```

I would like an array such as

```
$options = array ("option1" => true, "option2" => true, "option8" => true);
```

I can do:

```
$array = explode(",", $string);
$options = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
   $options[$v] = true;
}
```

I am wondering how to do it elegantly.

Comment: Might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (since your code works fine).

Comment: Interesting I didn't know about codereview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using array_fill_keys

```
$options = array_fill_keys(explode(',', $string), true);
```

Comment: Note for older environments, array_fill_keys requires php >= 5.2

Comment: If you are using something older than 5.2 I bet you have much bigger problems

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**array_fill_keys()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) function :

```
$string = "option1,option2,option8";
$options = array_fill_keys(explode(',',$string), true);
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/157622)